# kivy, cant access app.root property

Tags: python, kivy

I have the following codes in my main.py and spend.kv as follows

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class Manager(ScreenManager):
   currency = '$'

class SpendApp(App):
   def build(self):
      control = Manager()
      return control

class First(Screen):
   pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
   SpendApp().run()
```

spend.kv

```
<Manager>:
    First


<First>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Label: 
            text: 'Total spending'
            height: '48dp'
            size_hint_y: None
         Amount:
            height: '38dp'
            size_hint_y: None
            font_color: 1,0,0,1



<Amount@Label>:
   text: app.root.currency + '0.0'
```

when i run this the program crashes with the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'currency'
```

I know this is because of my referance to app.root.currency in my spend.kv
file:

```
<Amount@Label>:
   text: app.root.currency + '0.0'
```

so is there a way to make this reference correctly, without receiving this error?

Comment: You may want to make `currency` a `StringProperty`, so that label texts get updated automagically when `currency` is changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use following code:

```
<Amount@Label>:
    text: str(root) #
```

you'll discover that the root of `Amount` object is the `Amount` object itself because when you're defining it it's not in any hierarchy yet. You can access `root` widged only inside actual hierarchy:

```
<First>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Label: 
            text: str(root)
```

In this hierarchy, `root` object is definied as a object of `First` class, which is actually an instance of `Screen` widget, so you have to use `manager` attribute in order to acces your `Manager` class:

```
<First>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Label: 
            text: root.manager.currency  + '0.0'
```